# execute command is bash and extract data for it output

Tags: bash, shell

I have to extract some needed data from following command executed in terminal:

```
emulator -avd emualtor-666
```

After I execute in I've got such output in the terminal with a small delay in a second:

```
emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5566
emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5566
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
```

So I need to extract **port value: 5566** from the 1st line or **emulator-5566** from the second line. How can I do that?

I tied following script but it just gets stuck on doing returned any lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

emuName=$1

IFS=$'\n'
for line in $(emulator -avd "$emuName");
do
echo ${line}
done
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suppose, `emulator` is the Android device emulator. If my guess is right, you could pass the ADB port as `-ports console-port,adb-port`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
emulator -avd emualtor-666 | head -1 | cut -d ':' -f 3
```

or

```
emulator -avd emualtor-666 | sed -e 's/.*Listening.*://;t;d'
```

or

```
emulator -avd emualtor-666 | awk '/Listening/ {gsub(/.*:/,""); print}'
```